# Flutter NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I am getting this error while trying to fetch user data from the cloud_firestore but it's only getting me this error when for the first time, users login to the app and navigate to the profile screen. **if I hot restart or rerun the app, while in login state error goes away**.

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state:
flutter: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#f33a1):
flutter: The method '[]' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: []("name")
flutter:
flutter: User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
flutter:   SliverFillRemaining
flutter:   file:///Users/ishangavidusha/Development/MUD/mud_mobile_app/lib/screens/profile_screen.dart:102:13
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
flutter: #1      new User.from (package:mud_mobile_app/models/user_model.dart:23:22)
flutter: #2      _ProfileScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:mud_mobile_app/screens/profile_screen.dart:107:38)
flutter: #3      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:425:74)
flutter: #4      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:125:48)
flutter: #5      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4047:27)
flutter: #6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3941:15)
flutter: #7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
flutter: #8      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2348:33)
flutter: #9      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:760:20)
flutter: #10     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:280:5)
flutter: #11     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1033:15)
flutter: #12     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:975:9)
flutter: #13     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:891:5)
flutter: #17     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:249:10)
flutter: #18     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:207:3)
flutter: (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
```

[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXszS.png)

**And this is the user model I use >**

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String profileImageUrl;
  final String email;

  User({this.id, this.name, this.profileImageUrl, this.email});

  factory User.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return User(
      id: doc.documentID,
      name: doc['name'],
      profileImageUrl: doc['profileImageUrl'],
      email: doc['email'],
    );
  }
}
```

**FutureBuilder >**

```
SliverFillRemaining(
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: _getUserData(widget.userId),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      }
      User user = User.fromDoc(snapshot.data);
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(...),
          Container(...),
          Container(...),
        ],
      );
    }
  )
)
```

**And the Funtion DocumentSnapshot return >**

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> _getUserData(userId) async {
  return Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(userId).get();
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace says that the name of the function is User.from, but your code says User.fromDoc. Are these 2 different constructors? If not, then make sure that your documentSnapshot has data.

Comment: if you hot-restart you are at a different screen (most likely login screen) so the error naturall goes away until you hit the profile screen. The question from @ThinkDigital is relevant.

Comment: @ThinkDigital thank you for ur time. I don't really understand what it says. and these are not 2 different constructors but in stacktrace is shown as User.from.

Comment: @Marc Thank you too, no profile screen also perfectly working when hot restart it's only happened when user login and navigate to the profile screen for the first time.

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in the constructor so you can inspect your variables and see what's going on when it's called. That's the best way to get information.

Comment: @ThinkDigital Can you plz tell me how to do that?

Comment: I'll find you on Facebook. It's not easy to explain on here.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @RedEye Yeah, I did.

Comment: How did you solve it? I am having the exact same issue. I've tried everything I can. I might avoid using the future builder altogether.

Comment: I don't exactly remember how did I solve it. I think in my case it was something wrong with the user id. because I was passing user id through the widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

"StreamBuilder dirty state" warnings are usually shown if the snapshot data doesn't have a safety check. This ensures that the snapshot contains data. However, it seems `if (!snapshot.hasData)` is set as a safety check on the snippet you've provided.

From the details you've given, the error seems to only occur during first user login, but the error goes away on hot restart or app restart. I suggest checking if the method `_getUserData(String userId)` is able to receive the `userId` upon the first user login where the error usually occurs. Null seems to be passed on where the error occurs based from the logs you've provided.

```
flutter: The method '[]' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: []("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
```

If you are using above similar type code and then get same error , check the firebase documentId in collection name and snapshot